# Can't see terrain and objects after built Unity 5.5.1f1 on Android platform

Tags: object, build, unity-game-engine, terrain

When I play it in unity editor terrain and house is visible working fine here:

[This is the image which is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIRxX.png)

When I play it after build on Android device. The terrain and house is not visible here is problem.

I have done a little bit with texture size reduction also, no luck.

[This is the image which is not working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR3VT.jpg)

Comment: Your problem is solved?